# Testing localized strings in Flutter

Tags: testing, internationalization, widget, flutter

When I try to test Widget that contains

```
 hintText: LocalizationResources.of(context).writecomment
```

I get an Exception saying:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CommentInput(dirty, state:
_CommentInputState#32224):
The getter 'writecomment' was called on null.
```

So, is there something that I'm missing?
Widget builds nicely on a device and a simulator.

This is how my test looks like:

```
....
 final Widget widget =
        MaterialApp(home: CommentWallWidget(channelUid: '123456'), title: 'jelena',);

    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
```

And the LocalizationResources is just simple l10n:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'l10n/messages_all.dart';

///class containing localization logic and string getters
class LocalizationResources {
  static Future<LocalizationResources> load(Locale locale) {
    final String name =
        locale.countryCode.isEmpty ? locale.languageCode : locale.toString();
    final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(name);

    return initializeMessages(localeName).then((_) {
      Intl.defaultLocale = localeName;
      return LocalizationResources();
    });
  }

  static LocalizationResources of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<LocalizationResources>(
        context, LocalizationResources);
  }
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your test widget in the `MediaQuery` widget and provide your localization delegate. For more an example see [here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#an-alternative-class-for-the-apps-localized-resources).

```
final Widget widget = MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQueryData(),
  child: MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [LocalizationResourcesDelegate()],
    home: CommentWallWidget(channelUid: '123456'),
    title: 'jelena',
  )
);
```